# Is the product of two primes ALWAYS a semiprime?

Tags: prime-numbers

I know by definition, a semi-prime has factors that are prime numbers.  But what I'm unsure of, is if there is ever a case where the product of two prime numbers results in number with factors OTHER than the original two prime numbers?

Or will any product of two primes ALWAYS be *only* divisible by 1, itself, and the original two primes (or I guess the original prime if you squared it).

Comment: Yes, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: yes, this will always be the case.

Comment: Every number $\neq \pm 1$ has factors that are prime numbers...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed always a semiprime.  Think about it this way:

Consider a number $x = qq_1$ for some primes $q$ and $q_1$.  We know that if $p$ is a prime and $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$.  Well, what if some other prime $p|x$?  This would imply that $p|q$ or $p|q_1$, which is not possible because $q$ and $q_1$ are themselves prime.  Therefore, the only possible nontrivial divisors of $x$ are $q$ and $q_1$.

Comment: Could you explain why " We know that if p is a prime and p|ab, then p|a or p|b" , please ?
Also if this works for 2 primes q and q1 such that x =qq1, then it should work for products of more than 2 primes shouldnt it ?

Comment: " We know that if p is a prime and p|ab, then p|a or p|b" , is proved here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma